# Chocolatey - not able to find package from Artifactory

Tags: nuget, artifactory, chocolatey, choco

I am trying to install package using Chocolatey, and I am stuck at getting the package from artifactory.

I confirmed that **my.package.1.0.0.nupkg** is available in the URL: https://www.myarti.com/artifactory/packages

The artifactory requires 'access' For example below, username "u1" with correct password "pwd" has access, but "u2" doesn't have access to repo

I tried below choco commands, but no luck yet. You help would be much appreciated!

1. choco upgrade my.package --version 1.0.0 --source=https://www.myarti.com/artifactory/packages --pre -u u1 -p pwd

gives **The package was not found with the source listed** error

2. choco upgrade my.package --version 1.0.0 --source=https://www.myarti.com/artifactory/packages --pre -u u1 -p wrongpwd

gives **[NuGet] The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden** error

3. choco upgrade my.package --version 1.0.0 --source=https://www.myarti.com/artifactory/packages --pre -u u2 -p wrongpwd

gives **Invalid credentials specified** error

Comment: Can you show the output of the following command `choco list --source=https://www.myarti.com/artifactory.packages`

Comment: It asks me to enter credential, then got404 error (Not able to contact the source: URL), but if I copy/paste the same URL, and run in explorer, it works! (same credential)

Comment: I think it's something with the relation ship between jFrog artifactory and Nuget. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I'm having the same issue now. Thanks.